# EACCES: permission denied 192.168.43.41:8080

Tags: node.js

Hello everyone i am a beginner of node js while running my first server program cmd prompt shown

EACCES: permission denied 192.168.43.41:8080 this exception help me to resolve this issue.

```
var http = require('http');

var hostname = '127.0.0.1';
var port = '8080';

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
res.end('Hello from node server !');
});

server.listen(port,hostname, function(){
console.log('server is running');
});
```

this is the code i executed.

Comment: Hello karthikeyan S. Port 8080 is mostly occupied by other system processes. Use other port as like 3000, 5000 etc which are free.

Comment: If you are trying to execute it locally. It might run without any problem if the port is open. But looks like you are executing  on remote IP address (192.168.43.41) via command prompt.first check all your background processes and try executing the file using command `node filename`.

Comment: Please do upvote my comment if it has solved your problem. :)